# Erros em mysqli, parâmetros esperados

Tags: php, mysqli, php-7

Está aparecendo os seguintes erros:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\rede\profile.php on line 25
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\rede\profile.php on line 26
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\rede\profile.php on line 31
>
> Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\rede\profile.php on line 31

O meu código:

```
<?php
include("header.php");

$id = $_GET["id"];
$saberr = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'");
$saber = mysqli_fetch_assoc($saberr);
$email = $saber["email"];

if ($email==$login_cookie) {
    header("Location: myprofile.php");
}

$pubs = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM pubs WHERE user='$email' ORDER BY id desc");

if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
    add();
}

function add(){
    $login_cookie = $_COOKIE['login'];
    if (!isset($login_cookie)) {
        header("Location: login.php");
    }
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $saberr = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'");
    $saber = mysqli_fetch_assoc($saberr);
    $email = $saber['email'];
    $data = date("Y/m/d");

    $ins = "INSERT INTO amizades (de, para, data) VALUES ('$login_cookie', '$email', '$data')";
    $conf = mysqli_query($ins) or die(mysqli_error());
    if ($conf) {
        header("Location: profile.php?id=".$id);
    }else{
        echo "<h3>Erro ao enviar pedido...</h3>";
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['cancelar'])) {
    cancel();
}
```

Comment: Não teria que chamar a conexão aqui não?
    `$conf = mysqli_query($connect, $ins) or die(mysqli_error());`

Answer (score 0):

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\rede\profile.php on line 25
```

Que quer dizer que a função `mysqli_query()` esperava 2 parâmetros e você só passou 1.

---

**Porque esse erro?**

**A função mysqli_query() precisa de 2 parâmetro obrigatórios.**

1. A conexão. Onde você especifica a conexão mysql que irá usar.*(No seu caso, a variável $conecta que removeu do código por um erro anterior)*
2. A Query. Onde você passa o comando que vai utilizar no banco de Dados.

***Dica:***

> Quando aparecer algum erro relacionado a falta ou excesso de
>   parâmetros, procure entender a função e entender quais parâmetros ela
>   precisa para funcionar. Remover variáveis porque geram erro não é o
>   correto se você desconhece a finalidade da função.